# C++ : STL Container adapters

Tags: c++, stl, containers

In the below code, 'Second' is initialised to the copy of deque and 'fourth' by using underlying container. I feel glad if someone can explain me, When to initialize  to the copy of a container and when to use an underlying container.

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <deque>          // std::deque
#include <list>           // std::list
#include <queue>          // std::queue

int main ()
{
  std::deque<int> mydeck (3,100);        // deque with 3 elements
  std::list<int> mylist (2,200);         // list with 2 elements

  std::queue<int> first;                 // empty queue
  std::queue<int> second (mydeck);       // queue initialized to copy of deque

  std::queue<int,std::list<int> > third; 
  std::queue<int,std::list<int> > fourth (mylist);

  std::cout << "size of first: " << first.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "size of second: " << second.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "size of third: " << third.size() << '\n';
  std::cout << "size of fourth: " << fourth.size() << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think they do the same thing, create `queue` with copy of the underlying container. only difference is the type of underlying container

Comment: But when we can initialize it with a copy, why to again use the underlying containers? Does it has any specific uses?

Comment: because you want different underlying container? different containers have different performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When to initialize to the copy of a container and when to use an underlying container?

Both of these...

```
std::queue<int> second(mydeck);
std::queue<int,std::list<int> > fourth(mylist);
```

...construct and initialise a queue by copying elements from the container specified as constructor argument (i.e. `mydeck` and `mylist` respectively).

If you mean to ask why the second specifies a second template argument of `std::list<int>`, that's because `std::queue` can store the data in any container that provides the API functions it expects. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), that second template parameter is:

> **Container** - The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. The container must satisfy the requirements of `SequenceContainer`. Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual semantics:

```
    back()
    front()
    push_back()
    pop_front()
```

> The standard containers std::deque and std::list satisfy these requirements.

Of these, I'd guess that `std::list` would typically be more efficient for one or a very few elements (exactly where the cutoff is depends on object size, memory library performance characteristics, CPU cache sizes, system load etc. - it gets complicated), then `std::deque` will have better average performance and memory usage for larger numbers of elements (with fewer but larger dynamic memory allocations/deallocations).  But even an educated guess can go badly wrong for some specific use cases - if you care enough to consider tuning this, you should measure performance with each candidate container, and your actual data and usage, to inform your decision.  Having the container be a template parameter allows the programmer to choose what's best for their needs.

The parameter also has a default...

```
template <class T, class Container = std::deque<T>> class queue;
```

...so you only need to explicit specify a container if you're not happy to have it use a `std::deque`.

Comment: Is the first parameter obsolete once you specify a second parameter (the template argument?). E.g. using queue<string, vector<int>> seems to compile alright on my system. I can't see mention of that anywhere.

Comment: @Silversonic: both are still needed and need to be consistent (you might get away with them not being exactly the same if the two types can be cast to and constructed from each other - haven't thought about that too hard).   For your example of mixing ints and strings - it creates [compilation errors](http://ideone.com/aVRAe8) when you try to push a value into the container.

Comment: @TonyD Thanks for the reply. However you swapped around the element types in your example, and to me it still seems like a `queue<x, std::deque<string>>` (x is any element type) still operates fine as long as you accept the queue is implemented on top of its second parameter, `deque<string>`, and that the `x` type has no affect on the adaptor implementation. For example `d.push(20)` produces compilation errors, but this comes from the fact that `d` is a (implemented) `deque<string>`, not because of any inconsistency in the element types. If an issue arose with `d.push("test")` I could see it.

Comment: It seems like the main reason to keep consistent element types is to avoid programmer-level confusion on what exactly the underlying element type is. But declaring two different element types is fine as long as you accept/realise the underlying element type is the one declared in the second parameter?

Comment: per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) "The behaviour is undefined if T is not the same type as Container::value_type. (since C++17)"